# double field type declaration as zero

Tags: java, variables, double, declaration, zero

What is significant difference between following zero double variable declaration:
`0.0` VS `0d`

```
double d1 = 0.0;
double d2 = 0d;
```

I understand that both these are better than just `0`,because are more obvious for code reader.

However `0.0` VS `0d` difference is not clear for me.

Comment: I don't believe there is a difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. Have a look at the **[Java Language Specification, section 3.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)**

> > `DecimalFloatingPointLiteral:`
> >
> > 1. `Digits . Digits`<sub>opt</sub> `ExponentPart`<sub>opt</sub> `FloatTypeSuffix`<sub>opt</sub>
> > 2. `. Digits ExponentPart`<sub>opt</sub> `FloatTypeSuffix`<sub>opt</sub>
> > 3. `Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffix`<sub>opt</sub>
> > 4. `Digits ExponentPart`<sub>opt</sub> `FloatTypeSuffix`
>
> ...
>
> > `FloatTypeSuffix: one of`
> >
> > ```
> > f F d D
> > ```

Both are a `DecimalFloatingPointLiteral`, the first one type 1, the second one type 4

Answer (score 0):

Go check out the JLS section on floating point literals:

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an
>   ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can
>   optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d.

So it's a double if it's not suffixed